# How to observe database when using Entity Framework 6 with WebAPI 2?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to know how to view the database when using Entity Framework 6 with Web API 2.

Most tutorials I see show the ability to open the "Server Explorer" or "SQL Object Explorer" window to view "Data Connections", which will show a connection to the database created when deploying the current project that is using Entity Framework.  However, when I view these windows and refresh, there is nothing showing under "Data Connections"

I have hit a problem on a current project when trying to use EF6 with relationships in the models and It would help me to debug if I could see what EF has created. Perhaps the tables, sql, or visual class diagrams would be great, but I can't find any of those in the solution.

I can recreate the issue using Visual Studio 2013 with the following steps:

1. File > New > Project > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application
2. Select WebAPI project template > Click OK
3. Right click Model folder in solution > Add > Class > Create "Question.cs"
4. Add add few properties to the model.
5. Right click Controllers folder in solution > Add > Controller > Web API 2 Controller with Entity Framework
6. Select Model we created in step 4-5, Create new context "TestContext"
7. Build project

Now, i'm expecting that the scaffolding done by the steps above creates the TestContext which extends DbContext which defaults to creating a LocalDb instance on my machine. It's my understanding that LocalDb is included with VS 2013 and I have Window 8.1 which should have IIS on it.  I'm expecting to be able to see the database created when I build the project.

Is there some settings I need to change to view the database in VS2013 or does the Data Connection only show up if I have SQL server installed?

The only other difference I can see, is that most of the tutorials I reference are using MVC projects and since mine is WebAPI with EF added, perhaps there are some default settings / web.config settings that need to be enabled for me to see the database.

Speaking of web.config I do not see an explicit connection string in the web.config from the TestContext, which I was expecting.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Entity Framework will use a localdb database.

The actual database file will be created under the AppData folder of the solution.

Initially, the file won't be visible in the Visual Studio solution explorer, as the file is not included in the project.

Clicking the Show All Files button of the Solution Explorer toolbar to view the file.

Comment: Ah, that was too easy. Thank you.  I would suggest to update this answer to say that the user might have to use the "Show All Files button" in order to expose the *.mdf files within the AppData folder, but up to you.  By clicking on the .mdf file it then will show the database in the "Server Explorer > Data Connections" view. Again, thanks for the quick reply.